# Json Parser Exception unable to parse

Tags: android, json, parsing

This code is printing me json parser exception.
In this code I want to send latitudes to a server, but it will keep on displaying me two errors:

1. Json exception unable to parse
2. async task #1 error

Could you please suggest me what I could be doing wrong?

Here is my relevant code:

```
             package com.example.gpstracking;


      public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

Button btnShowLocation;

String lat = "";
String lng = "";
// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
// JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static String url_create_product = "http://dyandroidapps.netii.net/"
        + "android_db/DB_Functncreate1.php";
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled
            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                 lat = Double.toString(latitude);
                 lng = Double.toString(longitude);

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
        "Your Location is " + "- \nLat: " +  latitude
            + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
                // postData(lat, lng);

            } else {
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

        }
    });
}

/*
 * public void postData(String lat, String lng) { // Create a new HttpClient
 * and Post Header HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 * 
 * HttpPost httppost = new
 * HttpPost("http://dyandroidappa.netii.net/android_db/create_product.php");
 * 
 * try {
 * 
 * // Execute HTTP Post Request // HttpResponse response =
 * httpclient.execute(htget); HttpResponse response =
 * httpclient.execute(httppost); // String resp =
 * response.getStatusLine().toStrinkatyg(); try this // now //
 * Toast.makeText(this, resp, 5000).show();
 * 
 * } catch (ClientProtocolException e) { Toast.makeText(this, "Error",
 * 5000).show(); } catch (IOException e) { Toast.makeText(this, "Error",
 * 5000).show(); } }
 */

class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    // * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Sending markers..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    // * Creating product

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", lng));

        // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat from response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Posted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data not Posted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json Exception",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Only Exception",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        return null;
    }

    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.cancel();
    }
}

}
```

and my jsonparser class is

```
    public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            //HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    //      httpPost.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpGet.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

 }
}
```

and my logcat is

```
06-27 18:13:28.160: E/JSON Parser(2583): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
06-27 18:13:28.170: W/dalvikvm(2583): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b132b8)
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583):     at com.example.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:131)
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583):     at com.example.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:1)
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-27 18:13:28.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2583):     ... 4 more
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583): Activity com.example.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42554568 that was originally added here
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42554568 that was originally added here
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:418)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:322)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:234)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:153)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:559)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:300)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at com.example.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:109)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at com.example.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$1.onClick(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:64)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4295)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17456)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
06-27 18:13:35.250: E/WindowManager(2583):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 18:13:35.290: D/dalvikvm(2583): GC_CONCURRENT freed 189K, 10% free 9914K/11015K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 58ms
```

I have only one code that is posted here if it needs another code please suggest me

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
     * app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * 
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will
     * lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }



    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your actual response.

Comment: what is line 131 in AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java?

Comment: Response code means......? i didn't have other code except one which is posted

Comment: Thanks for your comments i havent response code please suggest me i am new in android so, it happens

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe the problem lies in this:

```
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", lng));
```

In your main actvity I don't see that you set these 'lat' and 'lng' variables (there are commented lines):

```
double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
// lat = Double.toString(latitude);
// lng = Double.toString(longitude);
```

So those two are constantly the same, as declared at the beginning:

```
String lat = "";
String lng = "";
```

Beside that, you have a NullPointerException in your 131 line. Please post it.

Comment: these lat,lng are not commenting ,it is commented by me for testing only,when it gives me null pointer exception then i coment this and pass another value and post the same code, but in real code it is not commented.    Thanks for telling me now can u help more ..........

Comment: You need to provide us your code, from line 131 (AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:131 line), you have there a null pointer exception, meaning that you are accessing something that doesnt really exist.